API Manager upgrade from version 2.6.0 to the latest one
We would like to know the procedure of upgrading WSO2 API Manager from 2.6.0 to the latest version  without losing data or having to reconfigure the application. We are using open source version.

The migration documentation and guidelines are not available publicly or to open source users. However, you can check the possibility of obtaining those by contacting the WSO2 support [1].
[1] - https://wso2.com/contact/

We tried to contact them several times during the past xeek but we still did not get any feedback using the same link. we even tried to contact them via discord and no answer
